# Updating a value to have 2 days infront of the previous date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, dateadd

I have a table called `FireTest` my standard insert into this table is :

```
    Dim ThisDay As Date = Date.Today
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("Insert Into FireTest([Date],[Type],[Comments],[Completed By],[Trans Type]) Values (@Date,@Type,@Comments,@CompletedBy, @TransType)", connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextBox1.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedBy", ThisUser)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransType", transType)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
```

So i add a new column into the SQL TABLE making the new insert

```
      Dim ThisDay As Date = Date.Today
      connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("Insert Into FireTest([Date],[Due Date],[Type],[Comments],[Completed By],[Trans Type]) Values (@Date,@DueDate,@Type,@Comments,@CompletedBy, @TransType)", connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay)
    command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@DueDate",???)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextBox1.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedBy", ThisUser)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransType", transType)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
```

How would I insert the value of this into the database but with a +2 days onto the `ThisDay`? Example : If `ThisDay = '22/04/2014'` then the value of `@DueDate` will be `'24/04/2014'` I know it has something to do with something along the lines of `DATEADD` but I'm not sure , any guidance around to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every DateTime object has a [set of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use for this kind of calcs.

In your case you need the [DateTime.AddDays(numberOfDays)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@DueDate",ThisDay.AddDays(2)));
```

This will add 2 days at the value of ThisDay and creates a new DateTime  that you pass as parameter for the @DueDate. Despite its name you should use this method also if you want to subtract days from the current date. In this case the value passed should be negative.

Comment: I have tried this method and granted it does insert into my database with 2 days ontop of my `22/04/2014` but it saves it as `Apr 24 2014 12:00am` when it should just be `24/04/2014` any reason why?

Comment: Nevermind but I've completed my error , thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@DueDate",DATEADD(day, 2, ThisDay));
```